# Mock DbContext and DbSet: Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Tags: .net, unit-testing, entity-framework-core, mocking, .net-8.0

I have a class which is the wrapper over EF Core DbContext:

```
using System.Diagnostics;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using DatabaseProvider.Interfaces;

namespace DatabaseProvider.Classes
{
    public class DatabaseConnector(DbContext context) : IDatabaseConnector
    {
        private readonly DbContext _context = context;

        public async Task<List<T>> GetAsync<T>() where T : class
        {
            try
            {
                return await _context.Set<T>().AsQueryable().ToListAsync();
            }
            catch (Exception exc)
            {
                Debug.Write(exc.Message);
                throw;
            }
        }

        public async Task<T?> GetByIdAsync<T>(int id) where T : class
        {
            try
            {
                return await _context.FindAsync<T>(id);
            }
            catch (Exception exc)
            {
                Debug.Write(exc.Message);
                throw;
            }
        }

        public async Task<bool> CreateAsync<T>(T entity)
        {
            try
            {
                if (entity != null)
                {
                    _context.Add(entity);
                    await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

                    return true;
                }

                return false;
            }
            catch (Exception exc)
            {
                Debug.Write(exc.Message);
                return false;
            }
        }

        public async Task<bool> UpdateAsync<T>(T entity)
        {
            try
            {
                if (entity != null)
                {
                    _context.Update(entity);
                    await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

                    return true;
                }

                return false;
            }
            catch (Exception exc)
            {
                Debug.Write(exc.Message);
                return false;
            }
        }

        public async Task<bool> DeleteAsync<T>(T entity)
        {
            try
            {
                if (entity != null)
                {
                    _context.Remove(entity);
                    await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

                    return true;
                }

                return false;
            }
            catch (Exception exc)
            {
                Debug.Write(exc.Message);
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I tried to test this class and I got error while test: Object reference not set to an instance of an object

My unit-test class:

```
using Moq;
using DatabaseProvider.Interfaces;
using DatabaseProvider.Models;
using DatabaseProvider.Classes;

namespace NUnitTests.DatabaseProvider
{
    public class DatabaseConnectorTests
    {
        private Mock<TestDbContext> _context;
        private IDatabaseConnector _connector;

        [SetUp]
        public void Setup()
        {
            _context = new Mock<TestDbContext>();

            var abouts = DatabaseDataFake.GetFakeAboutList();

            _context.Setup(x => x.Abouts).Returns(MockCreater.GetQueryableMockDbSet(abouts));

            _connector = new DatabaseConnector(_context.Object);
        }

        [Test]
        public async Task Get_About_List()
        {
            var result = await _connector.GetAsync<About>();

            Assert.That(result, Is.Not.Null);
            Assert.That(result, Has.Count.EqualTo(2));
        }
    }
}
```

And class that is create it for me DbSet:

```
using Moq;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

namespace NUnitTests
{
    public static class MockCreater
    {
        public static DbSet<T> GetQueryableMockDbSet<T>(List<T> sourceList) where T : class
        {
            var queryable = sourceList.AsQueryable();
            var dbSet = new Mock<DbSet<T>>();
            dbSet.As<IQueryable<T>>().Setup(m => m.Provider).Returns(queryable.Provider);
            dbSet.As<IQueryable<T>>().Setup(m => m.Expression).Returns(queryable.Expression);
            dbSet.As<IQueryable<T>>().Setup(m => m.ElementType).Returns(queryable.ElementType);
            dbSet.As<IQueryable<T>>().Setup(m => m.GetEnumerator()).Returns(queryable.GetEnumerator);
            dbSet.Setup(d => d.Add(It.IsAny<T>())).Callback<T>(sourceList.Add);
            return dbSet.Object;
        }
    }
}
```

Who knows how to fix that?

Class **DatabaseConnector** works fine when I use this class via Rest API controller, but have problem while I test it

Comment: The `GetAsync` method is awful, it will return the entire table to memory! Also don't do `throw new Exception(exc.Message, exc);`, just use `throw;` to throw the same exception.

Comment: @DavidG, okay, understood with throw. What should I do with GetAsync? Use sync method? And ur comment doesn't give me the answer why I've got the error while testing

Comment: Just do not mock `DbContex`. I would argue that it is rather pointless.

Comment: @GuruStron, omg, is that really what you can say about that? You show you unprofessional, I didn’t ask your opinion about my code, I asked why it didn’t work

Comment: @Kanasi Sorry if I somehow offended you, this was not my goal. I don't comment on your code, I give you advice based on my experience and it is up for you to listen to it or not. In my experience mocking `DbContext` was not worth the hustle - there are better options (IMHO). Personally now I prefer using testcontainers, if this is not possible - in-memory SQLite.

Comment: One could say it's not working because you shouldn't be doing it in the first place. I would agree with @GuruStron that mocking DbContext is almost always a bad idea

Comment: @DavidG, should I use dbContext without any wrapper?